# Pebble AppMessage not connected

Tags: ios, connection, message, sony-smartwatch, pebble-watch

I'm trying to write a Pebble Watchface. It should receive weather-information from my iPhone.
I'm using AppMessge for communication.
When the Pebble-App is open on my iPhone, the communication works. But when I close the app, the Pebble Smartwatch gets a APP_MSG_NOT_CONNECTED error.

Here is the code:

```
// Register callbacks
app_message_register_inbox_received(inbox_received_callback);
app_message_register_inbox_dropped(inbox_dropped_callback);
app_message_register_outbox_failed(outbox_failed_callback);
app_message_register_outbox_sent(outbox_sent_callback);

// Open AppMessage
app_message_open(app_message_inbox_size_maximum(), app_message_outbox_size_maximum());

// Get Weather first time

// Begin dictionary
DictionaryIterator *iter;
app_message_outbox_begin(&iter);

// Add a key-value pair
dict_write_uint8(iter, 0, 0);

// Send the message!
app_message_outbox_send();
```

Comment: What do you mean "When I close the app"? Are you talkting to an iOS app you wrote or to some JavaScript running in the pebble app?

Comment: I have my watchface. And this watchface sends an AppMessage to the phone. But this action will only be successful, if the Pebble-iOS-App is open or in background. If I close the app with the taskmanager on my iPhone, I will get this error.

Comment: Yes that is how it is supposed to be. Unfortunately Pebble cannot start your app if it's not running.

Comment: It is very annoying. Maybe they will add a background worker into the iOS app in a future update. This woould be fine.